# Why doesn't the GUI open?

Tags: python, class, user-interface

Hi I'm a bit new to class. We were required to create gui using class but as I tried to run the code it doesn't work and i dont know what is wrong with it.

```
import PySimpleGUI as p

p.theme("DarkGrey10")

class FuelCalculator:

    def __init__(self,select,dist):
        self.select = select
        self.dist = dist

    def distance(self,):
        self.dist = [

        #------Print Enter Distance------#
        [p.Text("Enter distance from point A to point B:")],

        #------Text Box------#
        [p.InputText()]
        ]

    def selection(self):
        self.select = [[p.Text("Select the automobile type:")],
    [   
        #------ Values[0] -------#
        p.Radio("Sedan Hybrid","Group1"),

        #------ Values[1] -------#
        p.Radio("SUV Diesel","Group1"),

        #------ Values[2] -------#
        p.Radio("Sedan Gasoline","Group1"),
        
        #------ Values[3] -------#
        p.Radio("Minicar Gasoline","Group1")
    ]
    ]
```

Comment: Take a look at the hello_psg.py file on the page https://realpython.com/pysimplegui-python/. It seems you need a `p.Window` that should contain all those widgets (Text, Radio, ...).
Your code also does not call the class you created.

Comment: Just definition for a class and no code executed, the same, maybe just with layout definition and also no window finalized by call `Window`.